Can we have two antd forms that share the same ref and have different handlers?
I am using Ant Design's Form component in a project where I have a filter implemented in two places.
Non-drawer filter: A filter form visible on the main page.
Drawer filter: A secondary filter form that opens inside a Drawer when needed.
Both filters share the same Form instance.
When I

Select a value in the non-drawer filter, the logged value is undefined (as expected, because of my logic).
Open the drawer filter (no need to submit anything).
Close the drawer and try selecting a value in the non-drawer filter again, it logs true instead of undefined.

It seems like interacting with the drawer filter affects the state of the non-drawer filter.
 const FilterWithDrawer = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <FilterComponent formRef={form} isDrawer={false} />

      <Drawer>
        <FilterComponent formRef={form} isDrawer={true} />
      </Drawer>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

/
 const handleValuesChange = (changedValues: Partial<IFilter>, values: IFilter) => {
   if (!props.isDrawer{
     handleFinish(values);
   }
 };



 <Form form={form} onValuesChange={handleValuesChange}>
  

